# Using different ScreenManagers, and Initialize solution?

Tags: xna

Using XNA C#, I have ScreenManager to handle backgrounds,  and ScreenManager2 to handle menu options and pause screen. There is also an ObjectManager, but I have no problem with that yet...

In the beginning of the game ScreenManager draws the background perfectly, and ScreenManager2 draws and handles the main menu options beautifully. But when I choose Play Game an error occurs. ScreenManager should be drawing the loading screen, but instead get the error "NullReferenceException was unhandled" at my:

foreach (GameScreen screen in screenManager.GetScreens ()) 
screen.ExitScreen ();

A method that had worked fine when I only had one ScreenManager, that appears to now have a problem with initializing because of the second one. Both ScreenManagers are inherited from a DrawableGameComponent each, therefore telling the game which to draw first, last, and everything in between.

I guess my question is, how would I re initialize the first ScreenManager, if they are in conflict with each other? In the method that causes the error, I've already tried:

ScreenManager.Initialize(); //before the foreach loop
ScreenManager.isInitialized = true; //an attempt to boolean this.Initialize() in ScreenManager

And many other boolean attempts... Which leads me to ask, can you disable and enable a class? Although inheriting from DrawableGameComponent I assume to remove and re add???

I apologize in advance if the question is hard to understand, its very hard to describe...

++++++++++++++++++++++++

I figured out it was because of the menu option belonging to ScreenManager2, and loading screen belonging to ScreenManager. So I painstakingly made a boolean system that allowed ScreenManager to add the loading screen, from itself... :/

Comment: Why can't you use one ScreenManager? I've had nor trouble using one for multiple screens.

Comment: When adding objects through lists, I found no simple way to add the objects to the GamePlayScreen, without creating an ObjectManager. Then all objects appeared over the pause screen, therefore making me create a new ScreenManager. I probably went the wrong way of dealing with it, but I'm still learning the ins and outs. Original problem had to do with list calling and drawing not working with GamePlayScreen, because it was a GameScreen inherited class... :/